# Both methods being called at the same time no matter what, how to fix it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, reachability

.h

```
- (void)checkForWIFIConnection;
```

.m

```
- (void)checkForWIFIConnection {
    Reachability* wifiReach = [Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi];
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [wifiReach currentReachabilityStatus];
    if (netStatus!=ReachableViaWiFi)
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"No WIFI available!", @"AlertView")
                                                            message:NSLocalizedString(@"You have no wifi connection available. Please connect to a WIFI network.", @"AlertView")
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"AlertView")
                                                  otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"Open settings", @"AlertView"), nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}



- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self checkForWIFIConnection]; // this does not show an alert...
    [self parseXML]; // ...if this is here, but if i remove this line i get the UIALert saying no INTERNET

...
}
```

How do i make him only parse if the checkForInternetConnection does not fail?

I assume it's like if self Checkforwifi... { do this } else { do that}

But my checkforwifi is void, and does not return BOOL, i tried to change the method but since i'm kinda fairly new, i failed miserably.

Any help?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)checkForWIFIConnection {
    Reachability* wifiReach = [Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi];
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [wifiReach currentReachabilityStatus];
    if (netStatus!=ReachableViaWiFi)
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"No WIFI available!", @"AlertView")
                                                            message:NSLocalizedString(@"You have no wifi connection available. Please connect to a WIFI network.", @"AlertView")
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"AlertView")
                                                  otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"Open settings", @"AlertView"), nil];
        [alertView show];
        return NO:
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if([self checkForWIFIConnection]) {
        [self parseXML]; // ...if this is here, but if i remove this line i get the UIALert saying no INTERNET
    }

}
```

return the status (a BOOL) and check it before calling parseXML, as seen above.

Answer (score 0):

In your .h, change it to:

```
- (BOOL)checkForWIFIConnection;
```

And in your .m, change it to:

```
- (BOOL)checkForWIFIConnection
```

Then also in the .m file, at the end of the method, add:

```
return netStatus == ReachableViaWiFi;
```

Then you can set up your `if` statement in the `viewDidLoad` method.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Have your `checkForWIFIConnection` method return a result:

```
- (BOOL)checkForWIFIConnection {
    Reachability* wifiReach = [Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi];
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [wifiReach currentReachabilityStatus];
    if (netStatus!=ReachableViaWiFi)
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"No WIFI available!", @"AlertView")
                                                            message:NSLocalizedString(@"You have no wifi connection available. Please connect to a WIFI network.", @"AlertView")
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"AlertView")
                                                  otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"Open settings", @"AlertView"), nil];
        [alertView show];

        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES:
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if ([self checkForWIFIConnection]) {
        [self parseXML];
    }

    ...
}
```

And you don't need to declare `checkForWIFIConnection` in the .h file. It's a private method not needed by other classes.